# How to setup a Squid Reverse Proxy?

Tags: reverse-proxy, squid

I have a website (windows IIS) that is very busy and I wanted to setup an SQUID Reverse proxy to offload some of the traffic. I wanted to know what are the best practices, and how to setup it up on a Windows or Unix server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Port Forwarding for Squid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31532233/port-forwarding-for-squid)

Comment: That question is very similar, but this is several years older. So wouldn't that be a duplicate of this one?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I managed to figure this out myself. You can follow the steps on this blog post to follow what I did to get it working: http://ashleyangell.com/2009/03/configuring-a-basic-reverse-proxy-in-squid-on-windows-website-accelerator/

Comment: Error establishing a database connection.

Comment: As a general rule, posting a link is OK, but you should include the steps in your comment so that if the link ever dies, like this one did, we still have the answer here.