# Port Forwarding for Squid

Tags: server, virtual-machine, portforwarding, squid

I'm trying to setup a Squid server on a virtual machine, and there will be another machine which will be connecting to the internet via Squid server. The problem is I couldn't find out how to get traffic with Squid server. I've read that port-forwarding is the way to go, and searched for it. Still, no examples/answers about that matter. I've wrote the rules for Squid, and tested it. It's not catching the traffic, at any level. Anything will help me out of this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for a transparent proxy?

Comment: @itshorty Yes I am, sir.

Comment: Than you have to redirect the traffic via iptables or similar

Answer (score -2):

I wrote a post about this a number of years ago to do something very similar - you can read about it here: http://ashleyangell.com/2009/03/configuring-a-basic-reverse-proxy-in-squid-on-windows-website-accelerator/